# third party library with anti-debug code

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-c++, visual-studio-debugging

We are using a third party library for our program (desktop application written in c++), library is protected with anti-debug code, encryption/decryption layers, garbage code, triggered exceptions and other anti-debugging techniques which makes it impossible to work on debug mode (on Visual Studio 2010).

There are only two functions I use in the library, rest of the code is getting bigger and bigger but because I can not run it on debug mode it's getting harder and slower to develop. So my question is what could be a practical approach to separate this library from my application and work with debug support, but still be able to use these two functions, as we need them for our application.

Comment: You could try to make two functions that return know results for a set of data. You can then test the application with the data, without the library and with the debug mode.

Comment: Actually I have tried this. We are using this third party library for security, data is not repeating it self so it is not possible to create some test data and use it temporarily. I really need to separate it from the application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to debug with the real behavior of your library (i.e. you cannot mock it up), I suggest you to encapsulate the library in a small executable that publish the two function through some kind of inter-process communication (ZeroMQ...).

In your software, implement a wrapper that publishes an interface that looks like the original library and calls the executable though your inter-process communication.

Since the library is in a distinct executable, it will not prevent you from debugging your program.

Comment: Actually that sounds like a good solution, what can you say about the performance? And also what is your opinion for using boost for interprocess communication? Can you compare it with ZeroMQ?

Comment: Speed is a relative notion, it depends on your project. If you are concerned by absolute performance, you should implement this solution only for debugging purposes. ZeroMQ is really fast for what it does, it can use IPC instead of sockets. However, as fast it can be, it is still slower than direct calls.  I never used boost interprocess comm, so I cannot compare.

Answer (score 2):

If you use only few functions from protected library, you can create own library with the same interface as in protected lib, implementing those functions with some stub data.

Comment: what do you mean by stub data?

I didn't try creating a new library with same interface but in my opinion it will result with the same thing as the anti-debug code will still be there.